# Upload file to JIRA REST API with PHP cUrl

Tags: rest, api, curl, upload, jira

I want upload a file to JIRA with REST API.

My code :

```
$ch_api = curl_init('https://website.com/rest/api/2/issue/SI-10255/attachments');

curl_setopt($ch_api, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch_api, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(["file" => "@t.txt"]));
curl_setopt($ch_api, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data','X-Atlassian-Token:no-check'));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "login:password");
curl_setopt($ch_api, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch_api);
curl_close($ch_api);
```

And i have this error :

```
the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found
```

And when i add a boundary, the file is not uploaded. The response from api was a blank array.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For upload file to JIRA REST API, not use the header "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"

And for the file, use this code :

```
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        $cFile = curl_file_create("file.txt");
    } else { 
        $cFile = '@' . realpath("file.txt");
    }
```